# Load more without Selenium with beauifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

im trying to do web-scraping of 100 reviews on the movie Mulan 1998 from IMDb, however with the following code it only loads 25 (all reviews from the first page, it has "load more" button):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl

excel = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = excel.active 
sheet.title = 'mulan reviews'
sheet.append(['title', 'review_date', 'review_text'])
    
source = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews?ref_=tt_urv")
source.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

reviews = soup.find_all('div', class_="review-container")
    
for review in reviews:
    title= review.find('div',class_="lister-item-content").a.text.replace('\n', '')
    review_date= review.find('span',class_="review-date").text
    review_text= review.find('div', class_="content").div.text       
    more_button = review.find('div', class_="ipl-load-more ipl-load-more--loaded")
    
    print(title, review_date, review_text)
    sheet.append([title, review_date, review_text]) 

excel.save('mulan review 8.xlsx')
```

i was unsuccessful in installing selenium, therefore i wanted to ask if there is another way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will click on load more button,it will produce a new link each time dynamically via API aka `AJAX` response. So you have to inject ajax urls  in the `requests` instead

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
urls = [
    'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7cjoqizdozag7gwh7mbsrdt4oarhzfmxvlnomwklyczuf43o6ss4oi2fjnzlcv4k5vpwgij3rxavgvrc4fh3xk7rdci',
    'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7cbpqm3diyye7gwxtojsrtsm2ab6y4hhzo5ziwr26fbyhvrl4ty4omzfzpzidfrndtutkdwxvupszultfj3so4pyucl5',
    'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7dzer45tmzid72uxrmbtqpq44abhzfmxvlnomwklyczuf43o6ss5oe4fxnzccr4k4gyilrq5gdyzwdh66tpk3her65y',
    'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7dziqm2tgzal7oxx3mrvrps4mbz6y4hhzo5ziwr26fbyhvrl4ty4oq2v5nrid5v5dtqwtdkd36p5cbngo6zt6ktweyiw',
    'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=g4wp7dzmqaytmzyl7kxhvnjsr3r4shjjtzpwzouokkd2gbzgpnt6uc23pazvzmjpb4dwuzntzuw22wncxv32ezsep2i5o'
    ]

data=[]   
for url in urls:
    source = requests.get(url)
    #print(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')
    reviews = soup.find_all('div', class_="review-container")

    for review in reviews:
        title= review.find('a',class_="title").get_text(strip=True)
        review_date= review.find('span',class_="review-date").text
        review_text= review.find('div', class_="content").get_text(strip=True)     
    
        data.append({
            'title':title,
            'review_date':review_date,
            'review_text':review_text
            })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)# to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                                 title  ...                                        review_text
0                                                Great  ...  This is really a Disney classic and one of the...      
1                                                 Wow.  ...  Definitely one of my favourite Disney movies e...      
2    One of the best animated movies ever. A "Best ...  ...  My Take: Yet another Disney classic. Impressiv...      
3                                             Amazing!  ...  I love Mulan! It has intense moments, great co...      
4                          Another great Disney modern  ...  Modern Disney is kind of a funny thing with me...      
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...      
118                                   Mephisto in Onyx  ...  Tony Bancroft directs "Mulan", an animated mus...      
119                      Not as bad as I first thought  ...  I'll be honest here. I started watching this m...      
120                     excellent Disney animated film  ...  once again we have another excellent animated ...      
121                                       Great Movie!  ...  MULAN is a great movie which has many memorabl...      
122                                           briliant  ...  Mulan is probably Disney's first attempt at a ...      

[123 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the "Load More" button in dev tools, [you can see that it's wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2vIr.png) in a `div` with `class="load-more-data"` and a `data-key` attribute. And if you [observe the "Network" tab of the dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzU1v.png) after clicking on the "Load More" button, you might see that a GET request has been sent using the `data-key` as the "paginationKey" parameter.

So now you can use something like the function below to keep retrieving the link to load more reviews:

```
def getMoreRevs(rSoup, rootUrl='https://www.imdb.com', lmSelector='div.load-more-data'):
  loadMore = rSoup.select_one(lmSelector)
  if loadMore: 

    if 'data-key' not in loadMore.attrs:
      print(f'not data-key attribute in {lmSelector} :\n', loadMore)
      return None

    dKey = loadMore.attrs['data-key']
    daUrl = '/title/tt0120762/reviews/_ajax'
    if 'data-ajaxurl' in loadMore.attrs:
      daUrl = loadMore.attrs['data-ajaxurl']
    if not daUrl.startswith('/'): 
      daUrl = daUrl + '/'

    lmUrl = rootUrl + daUrl + '?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=' + dKey
    return lmUrl 

  #else:
  print(f"! search for {lmSelector} returned {type(loadMore)} ",loadMore)
  return None
```

Then, you could wrap your code in a `while` loop or something like:

```
#imports 
#excel setup  
#def getMoreRevs...

reqUrl = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120762/reviews?ref_=tt_urv"
while reqUrl:
  source = requests.get(reqUrl)
  source.raise_for_status()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

  reviews = soup.find_all('div', class_="review-container") 
  #for review in reviews ...

  reqUrl = getMoreRevs(soup)

#excel.save...
```